# what is the difference between object.create(parentObject) and just assigning the parent object to the child object?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `object.create(parentObject)` and just assigning the parent object to the child object as shown below:

```
var child = Object.create(parent);
var child2 = parent;
```

They seem to be doing the same thing to me.
full code for reference:

```js
var parent = {
  get: function fn() {
    return this.val;
  },
  val: 42
};

var child = Object.create(parent);
var child2 = parent;

parent.val = 67;
alert(parent.val); //outputs 67
alert(child.val); //outputs 67
alert(child2.val); //outputs 67
```

Comment: Try assigning to `child.val`/`child2.val` and then see what happens with `parent`

Answer (score 1):

`Object.create(parent)` creates a *new* object whose prototype is `parent`.

The assignment doesn't create a new object, `child2` and `parent` both refer to the same object.

The prototype is only used when you try to access a property that doesn't exist explicitly in the object.

In the example below, assigning to `child2.val2` changes `parent.val2` because they're the same object. But assigning to`child.val2` has no effect on `parent` because they're different objects. And since `child` has its own `val2` property, it doesn't inherit this from the parent.

```js
var parent = {
  val2: 1
};

var child = Object.create(parent);
var child2 = parent;


child.val2 = 2;
child2.val2 = 3;
console.log(parent.val2); //outputs 3
console.log(child.val2); //outputs 2
console.log(child2.val2); //outputs 3
```